# Is there any policy on Stack Overflow for a situation when a user installs keylogger on another user's computer?

Tags: discussion, security

For nearly 3 years on Stack Overflow, I received great/enormous/gigantic amount of help from users. About year and a half after asking question a user openned chat room for me and asked to use TeamViewer I was afraid then and I thought it would be distilled stupidity if I agreed to do it so I passed but the person helped me very much either way.

Afterwards 2 people helped me on chatsrooms on Stack Overflow, so I became more trustful.

Today somebody also was helping me on Stack Overflow and I proposed to go on TeamViewer to make it a lot easier.

During session with that user, I got popup window about opening my filesystem; after the session, I found in TeamViewer's log:

```
014/08/31 18:17:12.289  2092  6492 S0   CT4 CT.Receive.CMD_MEETING_AUTHENTICATION From=242898059 To=707301261 L=53
2014/08/31 18:17:12.289  2092  6492 S0   CGatewaySession::ReceivedCmdMeetingAuthentication: CC=8 CT=9
2014/08/31 18:17:16.065  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\ 
2014/08/31 18:17:21.622  2092  6492 S0   CT4 CT.Receive.CMD_MEETING_AUTHENTICATION From=242898059 To=707301261 L=53
2014/08/31 18:17:21.622  2092  6492 S0   CGatewaySession::ReceivedCmdMeetingAuthentication: CC=8 CT=9
2014/08/31 18:17:23.738  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\All Users\ 
2014/08/31 18:17:27.993  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\ 
2014/08/31 18:17:34.923  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\ 
2014/08/31 18:17:57.039  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:01.897  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:14.368  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:18.271  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:21.472  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:22.736  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:25.853  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:31.574  1936  5408 G1   - Przetwarzanie transferu pliku...
2014/08/31 18:18:31.578  1936  5408 G1   - Zapisz plik C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Win32HostProcess.exe
2014/08/31 18:18:33.109  1936  5408 G1   - Transfer pliku zakończony.
2014/08/31 18:18:33.135  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:38.479  1936  4100 G1   Ending CFileTransferThreadServer... 
2014/08/31 18:18:38.479  1936  4100 G1   The CFileTransferThreadServer has ended. 
2014/08/31 18:18:38.479  1936  5408 G1   - Serwer transferu plików wyłączony.
```

After I restarted Windows, this: `C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Win32HostProcess.exe` started automatically and then crashed(I got Windows Forms error popup window on desktop refering to this file). I cut this .exe file and pasted it on desktop and scanned it online:

https://www.virustotal.com/pl/file/89f9653085a04745597becccceccc1b47d92f2c19e9bb0657c3671ea253541fa/analysis/1409507361/

It says it is keylogger.

I don't want to throw stones yet: any thoughts? Forward this situation to moderator or leave it alone?

EDIT:

Original log:

```
2014/08/31 18:18:25.853  1936  5408 G1   - Folder widoków C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:31.574  1936  5408 G1   - Przetwarzanie transferu pliku...
2014/08/31 18:18:31.578  1936  5408 G1   - Zapisz plik C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Win32HostProcess.exe
2014/08/31 18:18:33.109  1936  5408 G1   - Transfer pliku zakończony.
```

Translated:

```
2014/08/31 18:18:25.853  1936  5408 G1   - Directory View C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ 
2014/08/31 18:18:31.574  1936  5408 G1   - Processing transfer of File
2014/08/31 18:18:31.578  1936  5408 G1   - Save File C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Win32HostProcess.exe
2014/08/31 18:18:33.109  1936  5408 G1   - Transfer of file completed.
```

Comment: I've wiped the comments here, as I think the core issues have been addressed appropriately; in Josh's answer below, and the involved parties have appropriate contact information, if need be.

Comment: Well, I'll never be using fking teamviewer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry this happened, but I'm not sure it really has anything to do with Stack Overflow. You ask a stranger at the grocery store if knows which oranges you should buy; he invites you out to his van where he says he has really good oranges, and then takes your wallet. Do you complain to the grocery store? None of what happened is their responsibility.

On the other hand, maybe the analogy is incomplete. In that situation, you would call the police. There are no police to call here. I don't think it's possible or appropriate for Stack Overflow moderators to be policing off-site behavior, but if you have documentation of the whole process, *including the chat invitation*, it might be worth [emailing it to the SE team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) to see if they want to look into it -- if the user you interacted with is using Stack Overflow as a springboard for nefarious activity, that probably warrants a suspension. If the grocery store knew this guy was always hanging around, they'd probably bar him from entering.

Comment: @Yoda, I'm not a lawyer so I can't speak to the criminality of this specific alleged action but there are "police" to call for [reporting internet crimes](http://www.ic3.gov/about/default.aspx).